# Spring Boot Bellsoft Alpaquita docker container with buildpacks for Java 21 using maven

Tags: spring-boot, docker, maven, buildpack

I've been using Alpaquita buildpacks for my java 17 services with the following maven configuration:

```
<configuration>  
<image>  
<name>${project.name}:${project.version}</name>  
<builder>bellsoft/buildpacks.builder:musl</builder>  
<bindings>  
<binding>  
${project.basedir}/bindings/certificates:/platform/bindings/ca-certificates  
</binding>  
</bindings>  
<env>  
<BP_JVM_VERSION>17</BP_JVM_VERSION>  
<BP_JVM_JLINK_ENABLED>true</BP_JVM_JLINK_ENABLED>  
<BP_JVM_JLINK_ARGS>  
--no-man-pages --no-header-files  
--strip-debug --compress=2 --add-modules  
java.base,java.management,java.logging,java.naming,java.desktop,jdk.unsupported</BP_JVM_JLINK_ARGS>  
</env>  
</image>  
</configuration>
```

However, whenever I try to do the same after upgrading to Java 21, I get the following error:

```
[INFO]     [creator]       Warning: Dependency has no SHA256. Skipping cache.
[INFO]     [creator]         Downloading from 
[INFO]     [creator]     unable to invoke layer creator
[INFO]     [creator]     unable to get dependency 
[INFO]     [creator]     unable to download 
[INFO]     [creator]     unable to request 
[INFO]     [creator]     Get "": unsupported protocol scheme ""
[INFO]     [creator]     ERROR: failed to build: exit status 1
```

Execution default of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.2.1:build-image failed: Builder lifecycle 'creator' failed with status code 51

I am somewhat new to docker / containerization, i've read the Bellsoft Alpaquita documentation. My guess was that the Alpaquita flavor buildpack/JRE is not yet available for Java 21. Can someone please advise how to get this done for Java 21? Do I need to revert to using the default spring boot buildpack that uses the regular Bellsoft liberica JRE?

Comment: Looking at the Docker Hub listing for [that image](https://hub.docker.com/r/bellsoft/buildpacks.builder). It hasn't been updated in 10 months, which is pre-Java 21's release. You'd need to contact the image maintainer and ask them to update, or switch to using the official Paketo builders (or another builder).